# Logistic regression with ordinal independent variable

Tags: regression, logistic, stata

I want to see whether patients have a higher risk of seizures, the bigger their brain tumor.

My dependent variable is therefore "seizure (yes, no)" and my independent variable is "tumor size" ranging from 1 to 5.

There is a significant correlation if I just type

```
logistic risk size
```

creating a logistic regression for the variable, but if I run it as

```
logistic risk i.size
```

there is no change, but I can see the value gets more significant the larger the tumor.

I'm quite suspicious this change is significant but I think my problem is I can't get it to recognize it as an ordinal variable.

Perhaps the solution is simply not to treat it as ordinal but as continuous, and therefore my original result is true?

Comment: How is the tumor size variable created? What do the categories 1 to 5 mean?

Comment: It is 1 variable with a dropdown (1 choice) from 5 mm to 45mm if I recall correctly, in increments totaling 5 options from low to high size.

Comment: Given your explanation, treating it as categorical is the right thing to do.